# next 13 not-found.tsx keeps refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build a basic not-found.js/ts/tsx file for my next app, so if users stumble upon a route that does not exist, it just kindly points them back to the home or back screen since the default 404 not found screen looks very bland. I have it somewhat working in my my directory app/not-found.tsx, however the page keeps refreshing randomly. I am looking at logs and I believe this is happening because next is trying to fetch data from a route that does not exist, so it tries again and again. This looks very bad since the screen refreshes every few seconds and is annoying. I was just wondering if anyone has had this problem before since I can't seem to find anything like this online

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/dwada 404 (Not Found)
```

Looking at the logs, I am just getting this logged in the client console over and over, while the page refreshes.

Comment: I encountered the same. still couldn't figure out why though. I'm fetching data in my page, I thought it was the issue